# Set default queries for all users in TFS web UI

Tags: tfs

How can i set default queries for all users in Team Foundation Server when i am using Team web access?

Comment: With default queries, do you mean team queries? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to: Save a Team Query (Team System Web Access)**

If you have the required permissions, you can save a query to share with other users to a folder location that other users can access. They have them available by default. Queries saved in a location where the team can use them are called Team Queries.

To save a query as a team query, you must be a member of the Project Administrators group.

1. Create or modify a work item query.
2. Click Save As.
3. In the Save as Query dialog box, in the Name box, type a name for the query.
4. Click the Team query option.
5. In the Team project list, select the team project.
6. In the Description field, type a description.
7. Click OK when you are finished.